# Python 2.7 Save Json Loop Output into Variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, printing, output

Objective: 
I would like to save the output of the loop into a variable therefore I could then send the Email with the output.

## First Problem:

The JSON output is a repetitive blocks which can be inconsistent, so I'm not sure on the range, so i created a for loop, which would satisfy what I need. i know it's messy. The print statements identify everything I need; however I need to set all my print statements to a variable or variables that would give me more flexibility.

## Second Problem:

How do I end the loop?

Json Data Looks like;

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "attributes": {
            "name": "mike", 
            "color": "blue", 
            "size": "small", 
            "make": "mazda",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "John", 
            "color": "green", 
            "size": "big", 
            "make": "honda",



# Convert JSON Language to Script
jsonResponse=json.loads(json_object)
```

## LOOP

```
a=0
for i in range(0,100):
     a = a + 1
     print ("Name:",(jsonResponse['data'][a]['attributes']['name']))
     print ("Color:",(jsonResponse['data'][a]['attributes']['Color']))
     print ("Size:",(jsonResponse['data'][a]['attributes']['Size']))
     print ("Make:",(jsonResponse['data'][a]['attributes']['Make']))
     print (" ")
```

## EMAIL

```
# Email
from O365 import Message
myemail = x
password = y

o365_auth = ((myemail),(password))
m = Message(auth=o365_auth)
m.setRecipients(myemail)
m.setSubject('SUBJECT.')
m.setBody('print variable here')
m.sendMessage()
```

Comment: You could do, `for a in jsonResponse['data']`

Comment: Dude that's a great idea! I have a question though, would I have to still need to increment with a = a + 1? How would i then save the output which are print statements into a variable?

Comment: No, that will loop through the values of `jsonReponse['data']` and end when there are no more values.

Comment: Excellent, How would i then save the output which are print statements into a variable?

Comment: I would recommend saving it into a list of dictionaries for easy access, I'll post as an answer to explain.

Comment: ok, thank you so much; i got this error: print ("name:",(jsonResponse['data'][a]['attributes']['name']))
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict

Comment: `a` *is* a dictionary, you don't need to use `jsonResponse['data'][a]`, you can just use `a['attributes']`, I demonstrate this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `'data'` contains a list of dictionaries, so you can loop through them using `for a in dct['data']`

Since you want to save certain variables about each person, I would recommend a list of dictionaries with only the data you need:

```
dct = {'data': [{'attributes': {'name': 'mike', 'color': 'blue', 'size': 'small', 'make': 'mazda'}}, {'attributes': {'name': 'John', 'color': 'green', 'size': 'big', 'make': 'honda'}}]}

people = []
for a in dct['data']:
  people.append(a['attributes'])

print(people)
```

Now you have a list of dictionaries for each person in your attributes array:

```
[{'name': 'mike', 'color': 'blue', 'size': 'small', 'make': 'mazda'},
{'name': 'John', 'color': 'green', 'size': 'big', 'make': 'honda'}]
```

You could simplify this even further using a list comprehension:

```
people = [a['attributes'] for a in dct['data']]
```

Comment: Interesting, I think this may work, but I have an additional question the amount of people (attributes) will varies; so could i just state one block of attributes and loop through the entire data set?